# doc.data() is not a function when using condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
fetchPlaceDetail() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    getPlaceDetail()
    .where("placeId", "==", "p002")
        .onSnapshot(doc => {
            const { placeName, description, todo } = doc.data();
            this.placeName = placeName;
            this.description = description;
            this.todo = todo;
            this.isLoading = false
        })
}
```

[show error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbNM9.png)

It works just fine if I use `.doc('docId')` instead of `.where("placeId",'==',"p002")`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the doc is a collection, not a single document.

you should run something like:

```
fetchPlaceDetail() {
this.isLoading = true;
getPlaceDetail()
.where("placeId", "==", "p002")
    .onSnapshot(docs => {
        docs.forEach(doc => {
            const { placeName, description, todo } = doc.data();
            this.placeName = placeName;
            this.description = description;
            this.todo = todo;
            this.isLoading = false
        })

    })
}
```

[firebase / firestore docs queries Not working - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607915/firebase-firestore-docs-queries-not-working-javascript)

Comment: I want to query single document from firestore. It’s not array. Thanks anyway!

Comment: `.where("placeId",'==',"p002")` will return a collection so if you're querying only one document, it will return a collection of one document. if don't wanna do that, you should instead use `.doc('docId')`.